# DeleteById method returns null

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have tried to delete a row from database using Spring data `deleteById` method but it returns null.

ProductServiceImpl

```
public void  removeOne(Long id) {
    Product product = findById(id);
    productRepository.deleteById(product);
```

ProductRepository

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {
    void deleteById(Product product);
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/remove", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String remove(@ModelAttribute("id") String id, Model model) {
    productService.removeOne(Long.parseLong(id.substring(10)));
    List<Product> productList = productService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("productList", productList);
    System.out.println("deleted successfully !!!!");
    return "redirect:/product/productList";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you write it complex. Some code not necessary .First, you extends CrudRepository,it mean you don't need create custom method **void deleteById(Product product);** because crud contain method deleteById.
Second, Controller why you using : **@RequestMapping(value="/remove", method=RequestMethod.POST)**  . I think it must : **@DeleteMapping("/remove")** . And in controller only call.

```
@Autowired
private ProductRepository  productRepository;

@DeleteMapping("/remove/{id}")
public String remove(@PathVariable String id) {
    productRepository.deleteById(id);
    return "redirect:/product/productList";
}
```

Comment: i try this but nothing happen and no errors shown no action i think i need the request and post i'm trying to delete from a table in my project i also used js

Comment: You can avoid service class and only using Dao test it. I think it must work. Using postman test it.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Autowired
private ProductRepository  productRepository;

@RequestMapping(value="/remove", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String remove(@RequestParam String id) {
    productRepository.deleteById(id);
    return "redirect:/product/productList";
}
```

Comment: you don't need to use a model if you do a redirection.

Comment: if you send a param get or post use @RequestParam

Comment: it show me Syntax error on token ""/remove"", invalid MemberValuePairs , if i use method=RequestMethod.POST

Comment: The attribute method is undefined for the annotation type DeleteMapping

Comment: yes, it is correct because the method is delete. you must use RequestMapping not deleteMapping